# Cannot stop Zookeeper nodes from the ensemble formed in same machine

Tags: localhost, apache-zookeeper, ensembles

I am running a zookeeper ensemble of 3 nodes in the same machine. I unpacked zookeepers to three different locations. I can start all the 3 nodes. When I look at the status of the nodes, one node is a leader and the other two are on the follower state. However, When I tried to stop the nodes, none of the nodes are stopping.

I have three zookeeper servers like,

```
/opt/zookeeper/zookeeper1
/opt/zookeeper/zookeeper2
/opt/zookeeper/zookeeper3
```

My zoo.cfg files are,

/opt/zookeeper/zookeeper1/conf/zoo.cfg

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/opt/zookeeper/zookeeper1/tmp
clientPort=2184
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2889:3889
server.3=localhost:2890:3890
```

/opt/zookeeper/zookeeper2/conf/zoo.cfg

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/opt/zookeeper/zookeeper2/tmp
clientPort=2185
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2889:3889
server.3=localhost:2890:3890
```

/opt/zookeeper/zookeeper3/conf/zoo.cfg

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/opt/zookeeper/zookeeper3/tmp
clientPort=2186
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2889:3889
server.3=localhost:2890:3890
```

I have started each nodes by

```
/opt/zookeeper/zookeeper1/bin: ./zkServer.sh start
/opt/zookeeper/zookeeper2/bin: ./zkServer.sh start
/opt/zookeeper/zookeeper3/bin: ./zkServer.sh start
```

I tried to stop one of the node by,

```
/opt/zookeeper/zookeeper2/bin: ./zkServer.sh stop
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/zookeeper/zookeeper2/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Stopping zookeeper ... ./zkServer.sh: line 182: kill: (14255) - No such process
STOPPED
```

Then I check the status of the node,

```
/opt/zookeeper/zookeeper2/bin: ./zkServer.sh status
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/zookeeper/zookeeper2/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Mode: leader
```

I am seeking for an explanation of why I am not able to stop the nodes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This line tells me that the `pid` file that the Zookeeper `./zkServer.sh` script uses to stop the service is stale.

```
Stopping zookeeper ... ./zkServer.sh: line 182: kill: (14255) - No such process
```

I would suggest killing all the running zookeepers manually first (run `ps -ef | grep java` to identify other java processes running in the machine, and kill them manually), *then* starting them with the script, and once they're all up and running, try  to stop them again.